# Raspberry Pi cabal update never ending

Tags: raspberry-pi, cabal

I use a Raspberry Pi 1 model B with Raspbian, but when I try to do `cabal update`, the process gets stuck when it is "Updating the index cache file" and I have to force it to stop. I'm trying to install the latest version of pandoc here, but I cannot use `cabal install pandoc` either because of the same problem.

I tried to leave it running all night long, but when I returned there was a "kill process" line showing up.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor english :)

Answer (score 0):

If `cabal update` performance is particularly slow, it may be that you are using an old cabal version prior to the merge of [an important patch](https://github.com/nominolo/HTTP/commit/b9bd0a08fa09c6403f91422e3b23f08d339612eb).

The description explains:

> This patch improves `cabal update` performance by 10x(!) on my system.
>   Due to this issue, `cabal update` was using an extreme amount of CPU,
>   while it should be I/O-bound.  The reverse was taking 79s, now it
>   takes 0.01s.